# How do I install MathJax in GitBook?

Tags: npm, gitbook

I tried to install MathJax in GitBook with `npm install mathjax@2.7.6`.

```sh
$ npm install mathjax@2.7.6
npm WARN ml No description
npm WARN ml No repository field.
npm WARN ml No license field.

+ mathjax@2.7.6
updated 1 package and audited 1 package in 3.464s
found 0 vulnerabilities
```

I added the following codes to `package.json`.

```json
  "private": true,
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git://github.com/mathjax/MathJax.git"
  },
```

Now the situation is,

```sh
$ npm install mathjax@2.7.6
+ mathjax@2.7.6
updated 1 package and audited 1 package in 4.6s
found 0 vulnerabilities
```

However it raised the error `if (args[ii] == null) throw missingRequiredArg(ii)` while running `gitbook install`.

```sh
info: installing plugin "mathjax-pro"
info: install plugin "mathjax-pro" (*) from NPM with version 0.0.6
C:\Users\SU\.gitbook\versions\3.2.3\node_modules\npm\node_modules\aproba\index.js:25
    if (args[ii] == null) throw missingRequiredArg(ii)
                          ^

Error: Missing required argument #1
    at andLogAndFinish (C:\Users\SU\.gitbook\versions\3.2.3\node_modules\npm\lib\fetch-package-metadata.js:31:3)
    at fetchPackageMetadata (C:\Users\SU\.gitbook\versions\3.2.3\node_modules\npm\lib\fetch-package-metadata.js:51:22)
    at resolveWithNewModule (C:\Users\SU\.gitbook\versions\3.2.3\node_modules\npm\lib\install\deps.js:490:12)
    at C:\Users\SU\.gitbook\versions\3.2.3\node_modules\npm\lib\install\deps.js:491:7
    at C:\Users\SU\.gitbook\versions\3.2.3\node_modules\npm\node_modules\iferr\index.js:13:50
    at C:\Users\SU\.gitbook\versions\3.2.3\node_modules\npm\lib\fetch-package-metadata.js:37:12
    at addRequestedAndFinish (C:\Users\SU\.gitbook\versions\3.2.3\node_modules\npm\lib\fetch-package-metadata.js:67:5)
    at returnAndAddMetadata (C:\Users\SU\.gitbook\versions\3.2.3\node_modules\npm\lib\fetch-package-metadata.js:121:7)
    at pickVersionFromRegistryDocument (C:\Users\SU\.gitbook\versions\3.2.3\node_modules\npm\lib\fetch-package-metadata.js:138:20)
    at C:\Users\SU\.gitbook\versions\3.2.3\node_modules\npm\node_modules\iferr\index.js:13:50 {
  code: 'EMISSINGARG'
}
```

How do I install MathJax in GitBook?